# How to Count Features in a Feature Type in FME?

Tags: features, fme-form

I am reading around 120 spatial tables in FME.  I would like to export a spreadsheet or CSV using FME that contains the feature name (table name) and the number of records in that table.

So far, I've tried linking a counter to each feature type and the **[Statistics Calculator](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/statisticscalculator.htm)** to get the max value for the counter.  I then try to write the CSV with only **fme_feature_type** and max attributes.  I'm getting the **max** value output okay, but the **fme_feature_type** is not writing to the CSV.

Any ideas?  Also, do I need to add a counter to all the tables separately?  Or can I connect them all to a counter and then split it up somehow by **fme_feature_type**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a group by in **[statistics calculator](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/statisticscalculator.htm)** as fme_feature type, you need to expose the fme feature type from the reader.

Comment: Yes, in which case the "Total Count" output is what will contain your result. But the Counter method is equally as valid.

Comment: I had actually tried this and it was working but not outputting the fme_feature_type, just the count.  I tried exposing the attribute but it wasn't working.  In the end, I manually added **fme_feature_type** as a user attribute and it worked, even though I had already added it in the Format Attributes.  It's working now and this was the best approach.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not tried this, but it sounds like you should be able to use the [Counter](http://docs-cdn-src.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FMETransformers.htm#Transformers/counter.htm) transformer and specify your `feature_type_name` (or `fme_feature_type` if you haven't renamed it) attribute as the "Counter Name" parameter:

> Counter Name
>
> Create separate sequences of numbers to be assigned, either by placing
>   several Counter transformers with each having a different counter
>   name, or by choosing an attribute whose value will be used as the
>   counter name as each feature passes through. (In effect, using an
>   attribute to supply the Counter name is like having a Group By option
>   for the Counter.)

I also found this [discussion](http://fmepedia.safe.com/AnswersQuestionDetail?id=906a0000000ccyVAAQ) on FME Community Answers.

Comment: Remember to check the default start number 0, sometimes you might want it to start at 1 or -2 etc depending on your workspace.

Comment: The default attribute is _count you can use the AttributeRenamer to change that after that transformer.

Answer (score -3):

I decided to simply add readers for all the objects I needed a count for and hit run.  After it 'runs' the 'Features Read Summary' in the log has all the counts, and I just copied that into a text doc which could easily be converted to a csv.

Comment: This is fine if you don't have many feature types.  However, if you have an unknown number of files.  For example, you're reading thousands of shapefiles in a folder and subfolders, this wouldn't work.  Even in my example of 120 files, this seems like too many readers.

Comment: This solution is OK for testing while building a workbench, but doesn't allow for automation.